# Connecting to a remote MySql DB from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm running into a strange issue with a spring application. The application runs on a Tomcat application server and connects to a remote MySql database using a spring datasource. For testing purposes, we set up the application to connect using the administrator user on the DB. That setup works perfectly. However, before moving to production we need to setup a non-admin user in the db that the application can use to connect.

I went in and created a new user in the database with the command

> create user 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'password';

Then I set up the privileges with the command:

> grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on mydb.* to 'myuser'@'%';

To verify everything was set up correctly, I tried logging into MySql as the new user and it worked fine. What was not fine was the application. I tried to access one of our services and got the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'1.1.123.123' (using password: YES)
```

Just to rule out a possible permissions issue, I went back to the DB and added all the grants from the admin user to the new user. I refreshed the application and got the same result. I feel as though there must be a step I am missing somewhere. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

FYI the application.properties file for the application looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://myhost.com:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username = myuser
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Comment: One issue I see is that you're granting access to mydb, but in your datasource you're using my_app.

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a copy paste error. The actual url uses the correct value. I will update the post to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, this seems to have been a cacheing issue. The application is now working with the configuration posted.